# Converting kivy to apk issue: gradle building error

Tags: python, kivy, apk, kivymd, buildozer

I'm creating an app in kivy which i would like to convert into an APK file with Google Colab (method here: [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/3-ways-to-convert-python-app-into-apk-77f4c9cd55af)). I've tried many ways, but I always get an error after buildozer android debug:

*"Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0."*

Here are my requirements in the buildozer.spec file: requirements = python3, android, python-for-android, kivy==2.1.0, https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip, pillow, ffmpeg, ffpyplayer, ffpyplayer_codecs

Here are my permissions in the buildozer.spec file: android.permissions = INTERNET,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

After all, my error log after buildozer android debug:

```
Welcome to Gradle 7.4.1!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Aggregated test and JaCoCo reports
 - Marking additional test source directories as tests in IntelliJ
 - Support for Adoptium JDKs in Java toolchains

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.1/release-notes.html


<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [45s]> root project> IDLE<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [46s]<=============> 100% CONFIGURING [46s]> IDLE<=============> 100% CONFIGURING [47s]WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 33

This Android Gradle plugin (7.1.2) was tested up to compileSdk = 32

This warning can be suppressed by adding
    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33
to this project's gradle.properties

The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 33



<=============> 100% CONFIGURING [47s]> IDLE> IDLE<-------------> 0% EXECUTING [48s]<=------------> 10% EXECUTING [48s]> :compileDebugAidl<=------------> 15% EXECUTING [48s]> :generateDebugBuildConfig<==-----------> 17% EXECUTING [48s]> :javaPreCompileDebug> :checkDebugAarMetadata<===----------> 27% EXECUTING [48s]> IDLE> :mergeDebugResources> :createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests<===----------> 30% EXECUTING [48s]> :extractDeepLinksDebug<====---------> 32% EXECUTING [48s]> :processDebugMainManifest<====---------> 32% EXECUTING [49s]
> Task :processDebugMainManifest FAILED
/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/jvtrivia/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:35:5-81 Error:
        Element uses-permission#android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE at AndroidManifest.xml:35:5-81 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:28:5-107
/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/jvtrivia/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        Validation failed, exiting

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.




<====---------> 35% EXECUTING [49s]> IDLE> :mergeDebugResources<====---------> 37% EXECUTING [49s]> IDLE
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m 1s
9 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 1 up-to-date





  STDERR:

[DEBUG]:    <-------------> 0% WAITING> IDLE> IDLE
[INFO]:    STDOUT (last 20 lines of 75):
        
* Try:  
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. 
> Run with --scan to get full insights. 
    
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org  
    
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0. 
    
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.   
    
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings   
    
BUILD FAILED in 1m 1s   
9 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 1 up-to-date    
    
    
    
<-------------> 0% WAITING> IDLE> IDLE
[INFO]:    STDERR:
    
[INFO]:    ENV:
export LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs'
export PYTHONWARNINGS='ignore:::pip._internal.cli.base_command'
export NV_CUDA_COMPAT_PACKAGE='cuda-compat-11-2'
export NV_NVPROF_DEV_PACKAGE='cuda-nvprof-11-2=11.2.152-1'
export NV_LIBCUBLAS_VERSION='11.4.1.1043-1'
export VM_GCE_METADATA_HOST='169.254.169.253'
export GCS_READ_CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_MB='16'
export DATALAB_SETTINGS_OVERRIDES='{"kernelManagerProxyPort":6000,"kernelManagerProxyHost":"172.28.0.12","jupyterArgs":["--ip=172.28.0.12","--transport=ipc"],"debugAdapterMultiplexerPath":"/usr/local/bin/dap_multiplexer","enableLsp":true}'
export USE_AUTH_EPHEM='1'
export MPLBACKEND='module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
export HOSTNAME='ddc612308287'
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64'
export NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE_VERSION='2.8.4-1'
export SHLVL='1'
export OLDPWD='/'
export HOME='/root'
export NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_VERSION='11.4.1.1043-1'
export NO_GCE_CHECK='False'
export NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE_NAME='libcudnn8'
export COLAB_RELEASE_TAG='release-colab-20221201-060047-RC01'
export PAGER='cat'
export GCE_METADATA_TIMEOUT='3'
export KMP_EXTRA_ARGS='--listen_host=172.28.0.12 --target_host=172.28.0.12 --tunnel_background_save_url=https://colab.research.google.com/tun/m/cc48301118ce562b961b3c22d803539adc1e0c19/m-s-pch52kr1ysqv --tunnel_background_save_delay=10s --tunnel_periodic_background_save_frequency=30m0s --enable_output_coalescing=true --output_coalescing_required=true'
export TBE_RUNTIME_ADDR='172.28.0.1:8011'
export ANDROIDMINAPI='21'
export ENV='/root/.bashrc'
export NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE_VERSION='2.8.4-1'
export NV_LIBNPP_PACKAGE='libnpp-11-2=11.3.2.152-1'
export CUDA_VERSION='11.2.2'
export NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE='libcudnn8=8.1.1.33-1+cuda11.2'
export NV_NVPROF_VERSION='11.2.152-1'
export NV_LIBCUBLAS_PACKAGE_NAME='libcublas-11-2'
export LAST_FORCED_REBUILD='20221121'
export NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA='cuda>=11.2 brand=tesla,driver>=418,driver<419 brand=tesla,driver>=450,driver<451'
export _='/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
export ANDROIDAPI='33'
export ENABLE_DIRECTORYPREFETCHER='1'
export NV_LIBCUSPARSE_VERSION='11.4.1.1152-1'
export NV_CUDA_LIB_VERSION='11.2.2-1'
export NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE_NAME='libnccl2'
export NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES='compute,utility'
export NV_LIBNPP_DEV_PACKAGE='libnpp-dev-11-2=11.3.2.152-1'
export TERM='xterm-color'
export NV_NVML_DEV_VERSION='11.2.152-1'
export NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE_DEV='libcudnn8-dev=8.1.1.33-1+cuda11.2'
export NV_CUDA_CUDART_VERSION='11.2.152-1'
export ANDROIDNDK='/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
export TCLLIBPATH='/usr/share/tcltk/tcllib1.19'
export TBE_EPHEM_CREDS_ADDR='172.28.0.1:8009'
export PATH='/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin'
export NVARCH='x86_64'
export NV_LIBCUBLAS_PACKAGE='libcublas-11-2=11.4.1.1043-1'
export NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_PACKAGE_NAME='libcublas-dev-11-2'
export CLOUDSDK_CONFIG='/content/.config'
export GLIBCPP_FORCE_NEW='1'
export NV_LIBCUSPARSE_DEV_VERSION='11.4.1.1152-1'
export S2N_ENABLE_CLIENT_MODE='1'
export NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE='libnccl2=2.8.4-1+cuda11.2'
export NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE_NAME='libnccl-dev'
export KMP_TARGET_PORT='9000'
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
export TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH='true'
export LD_PRELOAD='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc.so.4'
export ANDROIDSDK='/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
export NV_CUDA_CUDART_DEV_VERSION='11.2.152-1'
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND='noninteractive'
export TBE_CREDS_ADDR='172.28.0.1:8008'
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON='python3'
export NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_PACKAGE='libcublas-dev-11-2=11.4.1.1043-1'
export SHELL='/bin/bash'
export PACKAGES_PATH='/root/.buildozer/android/packages'
export NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE='libnccl-dev=2.8.4-1+cuda11.2'
export NV_LIBNPP_VERSION='11.3.2.152-1'
export KMP_LISTEN_PORT='6000'
export NV_NVTX_VERSION='11.2.152-1'
export NV_CUDNN_VERSION='8.1.1.33'
export GIT_PAGER='cat'
export PWD='/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android'
export CLICOLOR='1'
export S2N_DONT_MLOCK='1'
export JPY_PARENT_PID='59'
export PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL='NO'
export PYTHONPATH='/env/python'
export NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='all'
export NCCL_VERSION='2.8.4-1'
export NV_LIBNPP_DEV_VERSION='11.3.2.152-1'
export GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW='1'
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME='/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
export ANDROID_HOME='/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'

[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/jvtrivia && /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/jvtrivia/gradlew clean assembleDebug

[WARNING]: ERROR: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/jvtrivia/gradlew failed!
WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Applying Java source code patches...
Applying patch: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --bootstrap sdl2 --dist_name jvtrivia --name JVTrivia --version 1.0 --package org.test.jvtrivia --minsdk 21 --ndk-api 21 --private /content/.buildozer/android/app --permission INTERNET --permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE --permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE --android-entrypoint org.kivy.android.PythonActivity --android-apptheme @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar --presplash /content/./jv_trivia_icon.png --icon /content/./jv_trivia_icon.png --orientation portrait --window --presplash-color '#8D99AE' --copy-libs --arch arm64-v8a --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir="/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_VERSION = '11.4.1.1043-1'
#     NV_CUDA_COMPAT_PACKAGE = 'cuda-compat-11-2'
#     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE_DEV = 'libcudnn8-dev=8.1.1.33-1+cuda11.2'
#     PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL = 'NO'
#     LD_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libnccl-dev=2.8.4-1+cuda11.2'
#     TCLLIBPATH = '/usr/share/tcltk/tcllib1.19'
#     CLOUDSDK_PYTHON = 'python3'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     NV_LIBNPP_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libnpp-dev-11-2=11.3.2.152-1'
#     ENABLE_DIRECTORYPREFETCHER = '1'
#     HOSTNAME = 'ddc612308287'
#     OLDPWD = '/'
#     CLOUDSDK_CONFIG = '/content/.config'
#     USE_AUTH_EPHEM = '1'
#     KMP_EXTRA_ARGS = ('--listen_host=172.28.0.12 --target_host=172.28.0.12 '
 '--tunnel_background_save_url=https://colab.research.google.com/tun/m/cc48301118ce562b961b3c22d803539adc1e0c19/m-s-pch52kr1ysqv '
 '--tunnel_background_save_delay=10s '
 '--tunnel_periodic_background_save_frequency=30m0s '
 '--enable_output_coalescing=true --output_coalescing_required=true')
#     NV_LIBNPP_VERSION = '11.3.2.152-1'
#     NV_NVPROF_DEV_PACKAGE = 'cuda-nvprof-11-2=11.2.152-1'
#     NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 'all'
#     NV_NVPROF_VERSION = '11.2.152-1'
#     NV_LIBCUSPARSE_VERSION = '11.4.1.1152-1'
#     DATALAB_SETTINGS_OVERRIDES = '{"kernelManagerProxyPort":6000,"kernelManagerProxyHost":"172.28.0.12","jupyterArgs":["--ip=172.28.0.12","--transport=ipc"],"debugAdapterMultiplexerPath":"/usr/local/bin/dap_multiplexer","enableLsp":true}'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libcublas-dev-11-2=11.4.1.1043-1'
#     COLAB_RELEASE_TAG = 'release-colab-20221201-060047-RC01'
#     ENV = '/root/.bashrc'
#     PAGER = 'cat'
#     NCCL_VERSION = '2.8.4-1'
#     TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH = 'true'
#     JPY_PARENT_PID = '59'
#     NO_GCE_CHECK = 'False'
#     PWD = '/content'
#     NVARCH = 'x86_64'
#     NV_LIBCUSPARSE_DEV_VERSION = '11.4.1.1152-1'
#     HOME = '/root'
#     KMP_LISTEN_PORT = '6000'
#     LAST_FORCED_REBUILD = '20221121'
#     CLICOLOR = '1'
#     S2N_ENABLE_CLIENT_MODE = '1'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE_VERSION = '2.8.4-1'
#     S2N_DONT_MLOCK = '1'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE = 'libnccl2=2.8.4-1+cuda11.2'
#     DEBIAN_FRONTEND = 'noninteractive'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libnccl-dev'
#     NV_CUDA_LIB_VERSION = '11.2.2-1'
#     NV_LIBNPP_PACKAGE = 'libnpp-11-2=11.3.2.152-1'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libnccl2'
#     LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs'
#     NV_NVTX_VERSION = '11.2.152-1'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_VERSION = '11.4.1.1043-1'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_PACKAGE = 'libcublas-11-2=11.4.1.1043-1'
#     GCE_METADATA_TIMEOUT = '3'
#     NV_CUDNN_VERSION = '8.1.1.33'
#     VM_GCE_METADATA_HOST = '169.254.169.253'
#     NV_CUDA_CUDART_DEV_VERSION = '11.2.152-1'
#     KMP_TARGET_PORT = '9000'
#     GLIBCPP_FORCE_NEW = '1'
#     TBE_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8008'
#     TERM = 'xterm-color'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     GCS_READ_CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_MB = '16'
#     NV_NVML_DEV_VERSION = '11.2.152-1'
#     PYTHONWARNINGS = 'ignore:::pip._internal.cli.base_command'
#     MPLBACKEND = 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
#     CUDA_VERSION = '11.2.2'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcublas-11-2'
#     NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES = 'compute,utility'
#     TBE_RUNTIME_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8011'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     PYTHONPATH = '/env/python'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcublas-dev-11-2'
#     NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA = ('cuda>=11.2 brand=tesla,driver>=418,driver<419 '
 'brand=tesla,driver>=450,driver<451')
#     NV_LIBNPP_DEV_VERSION = '11.3.2.152-1'
#     TBE_EPHEM_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8009'
#     NV_CUDA_CUDART_VERSION = '11.2.152-1'
#     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcudnn8'
#     GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW = '1'
#     PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE_VERSION = '2.8.4-1'
#     LD_PRELOAD = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc.so.4'
#     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE = 'libcudnn8=8.1.1.33-1+cuda11.2'
#     GIT_PAGER = 'cat'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '33'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: Additional info: if i comment the android permissions line in the buildozer.spec file, the buildozer can generate the apk file. But my app does not have sound in this case, because i use some .ogg sound files via kivy.core.audi Soundloader, which means i must have an acces to the memory of the device...

Answer (score 2):

Yea you already have the error in the permissions line, buildozer fails to debug with permission Write_External_Storage, instead you could use

```
MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

permission in place of

```
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

This would result in error free and working
apk after compilation